# Background-image don't resize correctly in the mobile screen using flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I can't resize correctly a bakcground-image with flexbox

HTML

```
  <head>
    ....
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 768px)" href="/css/mobile.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
     ....
  </head>
  <body>
   .........
   <section id="home-info">
        <div class="info-content">Text</div>
         <div class="info-img"></div>
   </section>
    .............
    </body>
```

css/style.css

```
  html, body {
      height: 100%;
     }
  #home-info {
      display: flex;
      height: 25rem;
     }
   #home-info div {
      flex: 1;
    }
   #home-info .info-img {
       background: #333 url('../images/some_image.jpg')no-repeat center center/cover;
       height: 100%;
     }
   #home-info .info-content {
         height: 100%;
     }
```

/css/mobile.css

```
  #home-info {
     flex-direction: column;
     overflow-y: scroll;
   }
```

The output in the mobile device is very flat background-image at the bottom or no image at all.
Even  being able to scroll up and down the mobile size screen.

Comment: You're using background of an empty div i presume, that's why there's nothing to see, use `img` tag instead

Comment: Yes, I did that, and it is O.K.